# Disable similar results from list.js

Tags: list.js

I use list.js, but it displays also similar results. For example I am typing Mar..., website displays also mur, car, man and etc. How can I disable them?

It is demo from codepen:

```
<p class="codepen" data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-default-tab="html,result" data-user="javve" data-slug-hash="isInl" style="height: 265px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;" data-pen-title="List.js - Fuzzy search">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/javve/pen/isInl/">
  List.js - Fuzzy search</a> by Jonny Strömberg (<a href="https://codepen.io/javve">@javve</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using fuzzy-search, if you change `<input type="text" class="fuzzy-search" />` to `<input type="text" class="search" />` it works.

[check it Codepen](https://codepen.io/thewasta/pen/mddZYgY)

Comment: Sorry, I saw your reply very late. It is working. Thanks